# getattr equivalent for function attribute

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to use getattr for a function like the following:

```py
class nums:
    num = 23
    num2 = 24
    name = "Adam"
    
    def aa():
        return num + num2
    

nums = nums()
print('The sum is:', getattr(nums, "aa()"))
```

But I get AttributeError: 'nums' object has no attribute 'aa()'. Is there something equivalent for getattr that does my requirement ?

Comment: For methods you don't need to add the `()` for the attribute name. It should be just `aa`

Comment: Side note: after ``nums = nums()`` you will no longer be able to access your class, you've overriden it with the instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the brackets in the `getattr` call to get the attribute and then add them in afterwards to call the function, except that still won't work because `aa` is missing the `self` argument

```
    def aa(self):
        return num + num2
    

nums = nums()
print('The sum is:', getattr(nums, "aa")())
```

Comment: It should be `return self.num + self.num2`, otherwise you get a `NameError: name 'num' is not defined`.

Comment: @paime - Yes thats true... I left that out because I'm not convinced that this is a real [mcve] and isn't what the op is asking about